# Neo4j - score based on suitability when searching for users

Tags: java, search, neo4j

I need to search users in my neo4j database based on their first and last name.
The query results should be sorted by how much they match The search query.
We expect the search input to be two words (for first/last or last/first name).

The query we've been using so far searches for users that contain the first name then uses UNION ALL to match users again but that contain the last name.
Let's say the search input was 'first last'.
So our query is:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.first_name =~'(?i).*first.*' RETURN u
UNION ALL u.last_name =~'(?i).*last.*' return u
UNION ALL u.first_name =~'(?i).*last.*' RETURN u
UNION ALL u.last_name =~'(?i).*first.*' return u
```

So a user that has the first name and the last name of the search input will appear twice in the query result.
Then in the java back-end we count how many times each user appeared (each user has a unique username) and then sort.

I want to avoid sorting and counting in the java back-end and simply use a single query if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a text-like search query, cypher is probably not going to be the way you're going to want to do this.   Neo4j actually supports legacy indexes that are implemented by Apache Lucene, and I recommend those for you because it's meant for text indexing.  Lucene even gives you a rich query language to improve your searches.

If you try to go the cypher route, you're going to end up writing a lot of complex back-end code, and your matches are still rather naive; in this example, you still need a character-for-character match on the last name and first name, and close misspellings won't find a hit.

[Documentation for legacy indexing starts here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-introduction.html).   Make sure to read the sub-page on "Scoring" because in the end, I think that's what you want.   Also make sure to check [extra features for lucene indexing](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html) because it will start to show you cooler things you can do (like compound queries) with Lucene that won't be possible via cypher.

The good news is that neo4j can do this, and it works really well.  The bad news is that some of this stuff is only available through the java API, and you can't do it direct from cypher as the example you provide supposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine it into one regexp:

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE (u.first_name+" "+u.last_name) =~'(?i).*(first|last).*' RETURN u
```

You might be better of storing both together in a "name" property. 
In Neo4j 3.x `CONTAINS` will also use an index but is currently case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

One way to check rudimental match precision I currently use in a search query is to simply check string length of the search key against the result string and order your result list by the calculated difference.

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.name ~= {searchKeyRegex}
RETURN u.name, ABS( LENGTH(u.name) - LENGTH({searchKey}) ) as precision
ORDER BY precision ASC LIMIT {limit}
```

I have to admit this is still pritty brute force, but so far it seems to do the trick.